# Why do my pancakes taste dry?

Tags: pancakes

I've tried various pancake mixes, and they always taste "healthy" and dry compared with the ones at a good cafe, and I don't mean greasy like iHOP's. What am I missing, fat?

Comment: We need more information to think about this problem. What is in the pancake mixes you've tried? How have you cooked them?

Comment: The most recent one has Brown Rice Flour, White Rice Flour, Corn Starch, Buttermilk, Granulated Honey, Baking Powder (Corn), Sodium Bicarbonate, Salt, Xanthan Gum. I don't know the older ones. I tried adding water or milk and cooking on a nonstick pan.

Comment: Are you gluten insensitive? Gluten free mixes like the one you listed are less likely to have a great texture/mouthfeel than standard wheat flour ones.

Comment: No but the others tasted similar.

Comment: The recipe list looks more for a self-rising flour replacement than an instant pancake mix.  At the very least, I'd have expected you to need egg or some sort of egg replacement if you were to get away with just adding water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More careful inspection of the good pancakes revealed that I was overcooking mine. The cafes brown the outsides but leave the insides slightly raw to be moist

Comment: Overcooking will do it ... but you may also want try letting the batter rest for 15-30 minutes after mixing it.  You often need extra time for gluten free flours to hyrate.